# How can I add dynamic examples into Cucumber feature file

Tags: typescript, gherkin, cucumberjs

Is it possible to add examples in future file as the result of js function? Or how differently can I generate example and pass them into future file.
In my example:

```
Examples: 
    | no. | projectStatus  | startDate  | endDate    | jobType           |
    | 1   | InProgress     | 22/07/2023 |            | Internal Billable |
    | 2   | InProgress     | 22/07/2023 |            | External Billable |
    | 3   | Finished       | 22/01/2022 | 22/07/2023 | Internal Billable |
    | 4   | Planned        | 01/01/2024 | 01/07/2025 | External Billable |
    | 5   | InProgress     | 10/02/2023 | 22/07/2024 | Internal Billable |
```

I would like to remove hard coded dates and replace them in a way something like:
const currentDate= new Date()
currentDate.setDate(date.getDate())
How can I pass this function into Feature file examples? I'm writing in typescript.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible. You would have to write something like "today + 3 days" and interpret that (possibly with a library). Or alternatively, mock the clock used by the application you are testing so you can control the progress of time.

Comment: yes, exactly. This is what I want to do, but I don't know how.  What kind of library could interpret "today + 3 days"??